# Reading Multiple ADC channels with a PIC18F24K22

Tags: microcontroller, pic, adc, c

I am having issues with reading 2 ADC channels in my code running in a PIC18F24K22.

One channel is used to read a potentiometer to control the speed of a motor ( PWM) and the other is reading a temperature sensor. They work fine individually but when I try to read both it does not seem to be working properly.  As I increase the duty cycle with the Pot something goes wrong, my motor starts making funny noises, however if I only use one ADC channel the motor is fine. Here is my code in brief:

```
while (1){
   unsigned char store = ADCRead();  // first function call (PWM)
   CCPR5L= store;
   float temperature= ADCRead1();     // second function call
   if (temperature>30)
   {
     LATC=0;
   }
   else 
   {
     ;;
   }
 }
```

---

```
//Functions
unsigned char ADCRead()
{
  ADCON0&=0b00000011;   // clear channel
  ADCON2bits.ADFM=0;  // left justified
  ADCON0bits.CHS=0b00100;// select channel
  ADCON2bits.ACQT=0b100;//Acquisition time to charge hold capacitor 8Tad
  ADCON0bits.GO=1; // Start conversion
  while (ADCON0bits.GO_nDONE)
  {
  }
  return ADRESH; 
}
    
float ADCRead1()
{
  ADCON0&=0b00000011; // clear channel 
  ADCON2bits.ADFM=1;  // right justified
  ADCON0bits.CHS=0b10000;// select channel
  ADCON2bits.ACQT=0b100;//Acquisition time to charge hold capacitor 8Tad
  ADCON0bits.GO=1; // Start conversion
  while (ADCON0bits.GO_nDONE)
  {
  }
  uint16_t value = (ADRESH<<8)+ADRESL;
  float vo= value*0.00488;
  float temp = vo/0.01;
  return temp;
}
```

Comment: "it does not seem to be working properly" is not much of a problem description.

Comment: Which specific PIC18 model this is?

Comment: Have you tried putting a tiny pause between them? Make sure the second ADC read function is called AFTER the first one finishes. Had timing problems like that, took forever to find, because the code looks correct, but it just doesn't work.

Comment: Hi it is a PIC18F24K22

Comment: a PIC18 is not a PIC16f, as far as I know - so I removed that tag.

Comment: Please add important details like "PIC18F24K22" to your questions in the future.  Thanks!

Comment: Doctor, doctor, I am feeling unwell; please prescribe the correct medicine or will something require amputation.

Comment: Yes I have tried delays in between the functions

Comment: The problem is when I read both channels, as I increase the duty cycle of the pwm my motor that I am controlling starts to sound all funny and strange cracking noises, so it feels like something is wrong with the code when I use both ADC channels as this noise dosent happen if I am only reading the POT

Comment: Try throwing away the first conversion in each function and making a second conversion which you then use. Just inline the code for a test. That will confirm or rule out a number of things.

Comment: Hi I have also tried that but it does not work

Comment: Try to avoid float on such a small 8-Bitter. You don't need it

Comment: You should give your `while`loop a constant timebase (e.g. 10 ms) and not running as fast as possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another way to implement your ADC to temperature function:

```
/*
 * File:   AppLoop.c
 * Author: dan1138
 * Target: PIC18F24K22
 * Compiler: XC8 v2.31
 * IDE: MPLABX v5.45
 *
 * Created on March 7, 2021, 11:37 AM
 * 
 *                        PIC18F24K22
 *                 +---------:_:---------+
 *      VPP RE3 -> :  1 VPP       PGD 28 : <> RB7 PGD
 *          RA0 <> :  2           PGC 27 : <> RB6 PGC
 *          RA1 <> :  3               26 : <> RB5
 *          RA2 <> :  4               25 : <> RB4
 *          RA3 <> :  5               24 : <> RB3
 *          RA4 <> :  6               23 : <> RB2
 *      POT RA5 <> :  7 AN4           22 : <> RB1
 *      GND VSS -> :  8          INT0 21 : <> RB0
 *          RA7 <> :  9 OSC1          20 : <- VDD 5v0
 *          RA6 <> : 10 OSC2          19 : <- VSS GND
 *          RC0 <> : 11 SOSCO     RX1 18 : <> RC7 RXD
 *          RC1 <> : 12 SOSCI     TX1 17 : <> RC6 TXD
 *          RC2 <> : 13               16 : <> RC5
 *          RC3 <> : 14          AN16 15 : <> RC4 TEMP
 *                 +---------------------+
 *                         DIP-28
 * 
 * Used the MPLABX Code Configurator(MCC) to generate the code to support the ADC and UART
 * 
 * POT:  10K ohm, Range: VSS to VDD
 * TEMP: TMP36, https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/TMP35_36_37.pdf
 */

#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"
/*
 * Function: Read_TMP36
 * 
 * Input: None
 * 
 * Output: float Temperature in °C (-40 to +125)
 * 
 * Notes: The Analog Device TMP36 has a 0.5 volt offset
 *        so it can indicate temperatures below 0C without
 *        making the output voltage negative to the VSS
 *        ground reference.
 */
#define ADC_VREF  (5000)    /* ADC voltage reference in millivolts */
#define TMP_OFFSET (500)    /* TMP36 voltage offset in millivolts  */
#define TMP_SLOPE   (10)    /* TMP36 slope in millivolts per °C    */
float Read_TMP36(void)
{
    float result = 0.0;
    uint32_t ADC_result;
    
    ADC_SelectChannel(TEMP);
    ADC_StartConversion();
    for(;;)
    {
        if(ADC_IsConversionDone()) break;
    }
    ADC_result  = ADC_GetConversionResult();
    ADC_result  = (ADC_result * ADC_VREF) >> 16;
    result  = (float)(ADC_result & 0xFFFF);
    result -= TMP_OFFSET;
    result *= 1.0/TMP_SLOPE;
    
    return result;
}
/*
 * Function: Read_Pot
 * 
 * Input: None
 * 
 * Output: uint8_t
 * 
 * Description:
 *  Returns an 8-bit value from 0 to 255 that represents
 *  the voltage of an analog input between VSS and VDD.
 */
uint8_t Read_Pot(void)
{
    uint8_t result = 0.0;
    
    ADC_SelectChannel(POT);
    ADC_StartConversion();
    for(;;)
    {
        if(ADC_IsConversionDone()) break;
    }
    result = (uint8_t)(ADC_GetConversionResult()>>8);

    return result;
}

void AppLoop(void) 
{
    float Temprature, Temprature_output;
    uint8_t SetPoint, SetPoint_output;
    
    printf("\r\nPIC18F24K22 ADC PWM temp start built on %s at %s\r\n", __DATE__, __TIME__);
    
    Temprature = Read_TMP36();
    Temprature_output = Temprature;
    printf("Temp: %f\r\n", Temprature_output);

    SetPoint = Read_Pot();
    SetPoint_output = SetPoint;
    printf("Set point: %u\r\n", SetPoint_output);
    
    for(;;)
    {
        Temprature = Read_TMP36();
        if(Temprature_output != Temprature)
        {
            Temprature_output = Temprature;
            printf("Temp: %f\r\n", Temprature_output);
        }
        
        SetPoint = Read_Pot();
        if(SetPoint_output != SetPoint)
        {
            SetPoint_output = SetPoint;
            printf("Set point: %u\r\n", SetPoint_output);
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to use the MCC to generate the rest of the code but this is what I created to test the calculations in the MPLABX simulator.

Note that I setup the ADC to use the "left justified" mode when reading the POT and TEMP analog voltages.

Answer (score 0):

The loop is very fast, but when you do both channels it is still very fast but the motor rate is being updated only half as fast, but even so could be something like every 40 microseconds (12kHz). It is possible that updating the pwm (CCPR5L= store) is interfering with the pwm itself.

You said you put in a delay, but did not say how much. Use something very slow, like a 1 second delay. A real-world rate for sampling a potentiometer is only 5 or 10 times per second, so a 100millisecond delay would probably do just as well.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply the frequency I am using is 15.6kHz and I have tried various delays from 1us - 10ms but as the delay is longer the motor makes more of a weird noise and sounds corrupted. should the delay be within the functions or where I call the functions e.g unsigned char store = ADCRead();                                                             
   __delay_ms(); 
   float temperature= ADCRead1();

Comment: Hi something else does not make sense if I remove the calculation part the motor works fine and I believe both ADC channels are working as they should, as soon as I put the calculation in for the temperature sensor it messes everything up again, any Idea ?

Comment: the `float`calculation is to slow, switch to `integer`

Comment: I did that still did not work, is there another way of doing the calculations with like bitwise operators?